# Run app in background : Windows phone 8 phonegap

Tags: c#, cordova, windows-phone-8, gps, background-process

I developing an application using phonegap. Which required to run in background to fetch location data and send to server.

I done this in android using [Background service plugin](https://github.com/Red-Folder/Cordova-Plugin-BackgroundService) and in iOS setting background mode in plist file.

Now i want to achieve the the same in Windows Phone 8. Please guide me how achieve this? What configuration changes required ?  Do need to write a custom plugin for this? ( if required is any opensource implementations available? )